# PrimeFaces Dialog Incorrect Header Size

Tags: css, google-chrome, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

PrimeFaces 4.0 Dialog headers fit well to dialog window in IE and Firefox but not in Chrome unless i move mouse cursor over the dialog header. When I move the cursor to dialog header it scales and fits the dialog window by itself. I get this problem for all dialogs I use not just the one I posted below. I only have this problem in Chrome. Do you know why this is happening in Chrome and how can I fix this?

The dialog codes and screenshots are below :

This is the status of dialog header when it's opened first

[image: This is the status of dialog header when it's opened first]

This is the status of dialog header when I move mouse cursor over it.
You see it got normal size.

[image: This is the status of dialog header when I move mouse cursor over it]

Dialog codes :

```
        <p:dialog header="#{graphAnalysis.charts.chartTitle} Distribution"
                  closeOnEscape="true" width="800" dynamic="true"
                  height="550" widgetVar="lineChartDialog" closable="true" 
                  onShow="loadLineChart()" minimizable="true" position="center" 
                  id="distChartDialogId" >
            <h:form style="margin-top: 20px;" id="chartForm">
                <p:lineChart id="lineChartId" value="#{graphAnalysis.charts.currentChart}" 
                             style="height: 450px;width: 750px" animate="true" legendPosition="e"
                             widgetVar="lineChartWg" yaxisLabel="Fraction of Proteins" 
                             xaxisLabel="#{graphAnalysis.charts.chartTitle}" 
                             title="#{graphAnalysis.charts.chartTitle} Distribution" zoom="true" />
                <p:remoteCommand name="loadLineChart" update="lineChartId" async="true" process="@this" />
                <p:commandButton type="button" value="Export" icon="ui-icon-extlink" onclick="exportLineChart()"/>  
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
```

Another dialog code :

```
       <p:dialog width="800" height="500" widgetVar="graphVis" dynamic="true"
                  closable="true" draggable="true" minimizable="true" position="center"
                  closeOnEscape="true" header="Graph Visualization" onShow="updateGraph()">  
            <h:form>
                <p:panel style="border: none;height:450px" id="graphPanel">
                    <p:mindmap value="#{browse.graph.root}" style="width: 800px;height: 600px">  
                        <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{browse.graph.onNodeSelect}" />  
                        <p:ajax event="dblselect" listener="#{browse.graph.onNodeDblselect}" 
                                oncomplete="details.show()"/>  
                    </p:mindmap> 
                </p:panel>
                <p:remoteCommand name="updateGraph" update="graphPanel" async="true" process="@this" />
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
```

My page structure is like that :

```
        <html>
           <f:view>
             <h:head>
                ...
             </h:head>
             <h:body>
                <p:layout>
                    <p:layoutUnit>
                        HEAD
                    </p:layoutUnit>
                    <p:layoutUnit>
                        BODY
                    </p:layoutUnit>
                     <p:layoutUnit>
                        FOOTER
                    </p:layoutUnit>                        
                </p:layout>
                DIALOG CODES HERE
             </h:body>
           </f:view>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is very nasty and there are some scenarios, in which it won't work, but in most cases header is displayed correctly now.

Add code to your JavaScript file:

```
function waitForDialogToLoad(dialog, initialWidth, counter){
    //if there was less then 50 tries, try again
    if(counter<50){
        //if dialog hasn't changed its width, it means it hasn't appeared
        if(dialog.width()==initialWidth){
            //increase counter
            counter ++;
            //and try again
            setTimeout(waitForDialogToLoad,10,dialog,initialWidth, counter);            
        }
        else{
            //set final width of header
            var header = dialog.find(".ui-dialog-titlebar");
            header.width(dialog.width());
        }
    }
}

function showDlg(dialog) {
    $.browser.chrome = /chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()); 

    //if the browser is chrome
    if($.browser.chrome){
        //find dialog object
        var dialogDOM = $("#"+dialog.id.replace(/\:/g,"\\:"));

        //set initial width of header
        var header = dialogDOM.find(".ui-dialog-titlebar");
        header.width(dialogDOM.width());

        //remember width of header
        var currentWidth = dialogDOM.width();

        //show dialog
        dialog.show();

        //set entry counter
        var counter = 0;

        //after 10 miliseconds check if dialog has appeared
        setTimeout(waitForDialogToLoad,10,dialogDOM,currentWidth, counter);
    }
    else{
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Then in view, instead of

```
dialog.show();
```

call

```
showDlg(dialog);
```